# Login / directory creator

Tags: javascript, php, html

all.

I've got a big ask, and I have no idea how to go around it.

I want to make a login / signup form, which creates a directory on the server for each new user. This directory, somewhat obviously, must not be publicly accessible by other users, and must automatically copy / make it's index.php file and subdirectories.

I'm afraid that I won't have much luck, as I've never made any form of encrypted login before, let alone a fancy automated one like this.

No code as of yet. Any help appreciated!

Comment: where this directory should be placed ? at the root folder ?

Comment: This is a very broad question to be asking. Try reading the [ask] section before asking another question.

Comment: when you need a new directory, in every login; or in every new registration? And why it's required?

Comment: Why do you need a folder for each user? And you don't need any encryption really, you just need to validate who is accessing it. I suggest you do the basics first - create a proper login system with properly hashed (not encrypted) passwords, use prepared statements, etc.

Comment: I'm quite sure you don't need separate folders for each user. If this is about having a user profile page/similar then just make one profile page outputting user data and depending on the URL (profile.php?id=1234) or something load the appropriate user and then output it using the general template. If this is for logged in users only then don't have a url param (profile.php) and load the user with the user ID you store in session when the user successfully logs in

Comment: @JimL I do need a folder per user, as each user has content that needs to be saved on the server privately. The context of this question is a questionnaire. Each user answers the question set once a day, and their answers are saved to their user folder. Rinse and repeat.
The users have to have their own folders, because they and only they must be able to view that directory and see their previous responses (have code for this).

Comment: It makes most sense to store the answers in a database, much simpler and no messing around with folders and folder permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need two things:

1st of all a system that you can create the directory and the files:

1 php (if you don't mind) file to create files:
Example code:

```html
    <form action="function-create-new-file.php" method="post">
 WHAT IS THE NAME OF YOUR PAGE
    <input name="file_name" type="text" />
 <br />
    KIND OF FILE YOU WISH TO CREATE
 <select name="file_ext">
 <option value=".php" selected>php</option>
        <option value=".html">php</option>
 </select>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Add Page" />
 </form>
```

This file will create your files and you should include this one to process it:

```html
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //has the form been submitted?
 {

 $file_directory = "./test/"; //the directory you want to store the new file in
 $file_name = strip_tags($_POST['file_name']);//the file's name, stripped of any dangerous tags
 $file_ext = strip_tags($_POST['file_ext']); //the file's extension, stripped of any dangerous tags
 $file = $file_directory.$file_name.$file_ext; //this is the entire filename
 $create_file = fopen($file, "w+"); //create the new file
 if(!$create_file)
 
 {
 die("ERROR, NOT POSSIBLE TO COMPLETE YOUR DESIRED INSTRUCTION");
 }
 
 $chmod = chmod($file, 0755); //set the appropriate permissions.
 //attempt to set the permissions
 if(!$chmod) 
 { 
 
 //error changing the file's permissions
 echo("ERROR IN THE PERMISSIONS FOR THIS ACTION, PLEASE CHMOD 0755 THIS FILE AND FOLDERS");
 echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
 include ("footer.php");
 }
 
 //defenition of the new page contante self created
 if (fwrite
  ($create_file, "this is the content of your new page!") === FALSE) 
  {

 echo "ERROR IN FILE: ($file)\n";
 }
 
 fclose($create_file);
 //tell the user that the file has been created successfully
 echo "The file was created! Take a look ate your file here - <a href='$file' target='_blank'>$file</a>";
 exit; //exit the script
 }
 
 else{ //the form hasn't been submitted!
 header("Location: function-create-new-file.php"); //redirect the user back to the add file page
 exit; //exit the script
 }
 ?>
```

Now second, you need to create a directory:

```html
<?php
// Desired folder structure
$structure = './depth1/depth2/depth3/';

// To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
// to mkdir() must be specified.

if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}

// ...
?>
```

Please check also this link: [How to Create a Directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Now you need to create the login system for the users. You can do that once again in PHP.

```html
<?php

session_start();
function encode_5t_base64($str)
{
  for($i=0; $i<5;$i++)
  {
    $str=strrev(base64_encode($str));
  }
  return $str;
}
function jh_password_protection($pass_string)
{
 $pass_string = encode_5t_base64($pass_string);
 $pass_string = md5($pass_string);
 $pass_string = sha1($pass_string);
 return $pass_string;
}
function registerUser($user,$pass1,$pass2) 
{
 $errorText = '';
 if ($pass1 != $pass2) $errorText = "Password must be the same";
 elseif (strlen($pass1) < 6) $errorText = "Password too short";
 $pfile = fopen("some/path/to/store/member/password.php","a+");
    rewind($pfile);
    while (!feof($pfile)) 
 {
        $line = fgets($pfile);
        $tmp = explode(':', $line);
        if ($tmp[0] == $user) 
  {
            $errorText = "That user already exists"; // check it you made duplicated members
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($errorText == '')
 {
  $userpass = jh_password_protection($pass1);
     
  fwrite($pfile, "\r\n$user:$userpass");
    }
    fclose($pfile);
 return $errorText;
}
function loginUser($user,$pass)
{
 $errorText = '';
 $validUser = false;
 $pfile = fopen("path/to/your/user/page.php","r");
    rewind($pfile);

    while (!feof($pfile)) {
        $line = fgets($pfile);
        $tmp = explode(':', $line);
        if ($tmp[0] == $user) 
  {
            if (trim($tmp[1]) == trim(jh_password_protection($pass)))
   {
             $validUser= true;
             $_SESSION['userName'] = $user;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
 
    fclose($pfile);
    if ($validUser != true) 
 $errorText = "That went wrong"; // failed login message
    
    if ($validUser == true) $_SESSION['validUser'] = true;
    else $_SESSION['validUser'] = false;
 
 return $errorText; 
}
function logoutUser()
{
 unset($_SESSION['validUser']);
 unset($_SESSION['userName']);
}
function checkUser()
{
 if ((!isset($_SESSION['validUser'])) || ($_SESSION['validUser'] != true))
 {
  header('Location: path/to/your/user/page.php'); // Your user location
  exit(); 
  
 }
}
?>
```

Now lets make the login system, first step, create a login page as you desire and place this code under content type tag:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Sample login system form:

```html
<?php
 if ($error == '') {
  echo "Welcome";
  echo "<a href='./path/to/your/member/area/'>Proceed</a>";
  }
  else echo " $error ";
 ?>
 
 
 <?php if ($error != '') {?>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"> 
 <br/><br/>
 <label>USERNAME</label>
 <br/><br/>
 <input name="username" type="text">
 <br/><br/>
 <label>PASSWORD</label>
 <br/><br/>
 <input name="password" type="password">
 <br/><br/>
 <input value="LOGIN" name="submitBtn" type="submit">
 </form>
    <?php } 
 if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){ 
 ?>
```

at the top of your page just include this:

```html
<?php
 require_once('file/that/operates/the/login.php');
 $error = 'wow that was wrong';
 if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
 $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
 $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
 $error = loginUser($username,$password);}
?>
```

I think i didnt forgot nothing here, but let me know if that helps.

Comment: This looks brilliant! I will definitely try it out next chance I get (within a few hours). Will let you know how I go.

Comment: i had this in a old system of mine, but you should do this in mysql. i can help you on that too. Best regards, all the best

Comment: Okay. I hit an issue. Don't know how to go around it. See [link](https://preview.ibb.co/mEZTO5/Screen_Shot_2017_05_11_at_4_57_10_pm.png). Note that line 139 is the final line of my document.

Comment: I worked my way around it, and this has done the trick. Thanks very much!

Comment: just seen it now sorry mate different day fuse ;) but let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

IMO storing the data in a database instead of files would be cleaner and easier.

However if you really need to go with separate folders here's a solution:

- Create a simple login/signup form.
- On signup, create the user folder in a parent folder you will name for example **uploads**.
- Then you just have to configure your server (you can achieve this with .htaccess) so that every request to the **uploads** folder gets redirected to a controller (for example **index.php**)
- In **index.php**, check that the user is logged in and that the folder he's trying to access belongs to him. If it does, render the requested file, if not, render an error message.

Comment: Thanks. That's going to be helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

in your php file that handles the register function
after a success registration you should add

```
mkdir("yourtargetpath/" . $username, 0700);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. This just creates a directory that only the server user that owns the directory can read, write or and exectute ([chmod permissions](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/unix/command/chmod-permissions-flags-explained-600-0600-700-777-100-etc)). OP wants a fully fledged, encrypted login system.